# Remove KML layers from map PARTIALLY

Tags: google-maps, kml, google-earth-plugin

How do I remove not all the kml layers from the map, but partially?
For example, I need to remove all raster layers, not vector?

This is my site: http://www.stonegraves.su/data/stonegraves_3d_model_2011_1.html
I want to remove all raster layers (select only one raster layer from
the list and remove previously opened), not vector layers (from the
chekbox).

Comment: So this is a Google Earth Plugin question, not a maps question. I re-tagged. What is the problem you're having? What's the error message?

Comment: Yes, it is not Google Maps question, original tag was "kml", "google-maps" tag was added later by another user.

Comment: There is no error message et all. I want to remove previous kml(raster) at the selecting new in the list box, but do not reload opened kml(placemark). Problem site is http://www.stonegraves.su/data/stonegraves_3d_model_2011_1.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to remove part of a KMLLayer. However, you could instead load two separate layers and remove one or the other of them.

Comment: Yes, I have some KMLLayers, that added from two different sources - combobox (for raster, previous selection should be removed), and checkboxes (for placemarks). Placemarks should remain intact, but previous selection from combobox should be removed before downloading new raster.

Comment: Thanks a lot, the problem is solved (by Anatoly Nazimov, Murmansk, Russia)